# OpenCV error with detectMultiScale in python

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

when I start my program on vscode I got this error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsQvz.png)

Whereas when I execute the .py the program work well. I don't understand why vscode don't run the the python file. Here is my code:

```
import cv2


img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("cascade.xml")

while(True):
    ret, frame = img.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,4)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
      cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it in a system terminal outside of VS Code? In the screenshot you provided, it shows that there is a problem with the ".cpp" file.

Comment: I tried to run the code with the cmd and it work very well thx. I don't understand why it wasn't working on vscode

Comment: -The internal terminal used by VS Code is an integrated terminal from the system. Therefore, it is recommended that you check the python environment currently used by the VS Code terminal (python --version) and try to reinstall the "Python" extension and then reopen VS Code.